# Create Cluster Configuration in Ignite web console is not working

Tags: ignite, gridgain

[Create CLuster COnfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shbwA.png) The "Create Cluster Configuration button" not working from webconsole https://console.gridgain.com/configuration/overview..

Moreover when i launch the console.gridgain.com from my browser.  I am getting below error

Failed to load clusters: Cannot start/stop cache within lock or transaction [cacheNames=ClusterCache, operation=dynamicStartCache]

Comment: I am newly setting up the apache ignite and ignite web console

Answer (score 0):

I think this means you have tried to use `getOrCreateCache` from within an Apache Ignite `Transaction`.

I recommend getting all of your caches before you start a Transaction. Maybe there's something else but you will need to share more details.

Comment: THis is the first time creating cluster from web console . The "Create CLuster Configuration button does not pop up anything" TH.https://console.gridgain.com/configuration/overview

Comment: Please provide steps to reproduce and/or screenshots/stack traces.

Comment: Added screen, DO i need any licence to create cluster.. WHen i click the "Create Cluster Configuration" Nothing happens

Comment: @alamar I confirm the issue, same happens for me too. Steps to reproduce:
1. Signup for Web Console (console.gridgain.com).
2. After automatic redirect to configurations (the default screen), the issue reported by OP happens. The "Create Configuration" button leads to the new configuration screen, but the transition is blocked by the same error.
I suspect it's something wrong with data in Web Console DB on console.gridgain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Gridgain ignite team has made a fix and it is now resolved.